# How to Activate SqlDataSource on Button Click

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

How to Activate SqlDataSource on Button Click , i have two sql data sources, 2 textboxes, two buttons and a grid view

i want to bind 1 sqldatasource to one on button click and the other to another button eg.

```
GridView2.DataSource =SqlDataSource2; 
GridView2.DataBind();
```

except it does not work and it wont output anything. when i test query it works just fine

cs#

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace IEIMS
{
    public partial class Master : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        protected void Button1_Click2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource3;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

asp code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Master.aspx.cs" Inherits="IEIMS.Master" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

</head>
<link href="Plugins/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <link href="Plugins/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <link href="Plugins/login.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Plugins/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Plugins/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">IEIS</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">View <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="master.aspx">Master List</a></li>
            <li><a href="Deployed.aspx">Inventory List</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Deploy <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="Account.aspx">Deploy Items</a></li>
            <li><a href="Returned.aspx">Return Itmes</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="Add.aspx">Add Desktop/Laptop</a></li>
            <li><a href="AddType2.aspx">Add Accessories</a></li>
            <li><a href="additem.aspx">Add Model</a></li>
            <li><a href="defective.aspx">Add Defective Items</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
         <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Print<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="export.aspx">Export Master List</a></li>
            <li><a href="Default.aspx">Print Accountability Form</a></li>
            <li><a href="returnslip.aspx">Print Return Slip</a></li>

            <li class="divider"></li>

          </ul>
        </li>
      <li><a href="Login.aspx">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>


    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
    <div>



    </div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>Desktop</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Laptop</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Keyboard</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Mouse</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Avaya</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server"  
            Text="Search" onclick="Button1_Click2" Width="218px" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br />
         <br />
         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" 
             ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MonitorConnectionString5 %>" 
             SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [masterlist]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MonitorConnectionString5 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [masterlist] WHERE ([itemname] = @itemname)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownList1" Name="itemname" 
                    PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" 
            Text="Search Serial Number" />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MonitorConnectionString5 %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [masterlist] WHERE ([serialnumber] = @serialnumber)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="serialnumber" 
                    PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            CssClass="table" AllowSorting="True" 
        CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" >
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should work. Can you show your code?

Comment: @RahulSingh added code above

Comment: Your code is fine, Just check the `connection string` and your query, Simply bind gridview with `DataSourceID` for testing purpose.

Comment: connection string works fine , together with the binding from grid view let me post my html code

Comment: Microsoft doesn't recommend you use `SqlDataSource` anymore.

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns="False"  change it to true.if not worked even,see eval() function using article in gridview .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have set `AutoGenerateColumns` as false and you are not binding the columns explicitly, so set it to `true` if you want to bind it automatically like this:-

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
```